# How to count each time a command is used by someone?

Tags: python

Complete Noob at programming here, trying to work on a discord bot in python for one of our servers. The only thing I can't figure out is how to add a counter for how many times a command has been used? Below is the code I've tried. (Im sorry it probably will make your eyes bleed but like I said, 100% noob)

I've searched up lots of counters online, and all of them seem to kind of mirror the format I have here

```
count = 0
@client.command()
async def addcan(ctx):
    count += 1
        await ctx.send(count)
        return count
```

I need it to simply print out the new can total. !addcan once and you get the response of 1, !addcan a second time the response is 2, etc... I keep getting a variable declaration error, and im not sure why! 
Help is appreciated, thanks to anyone who does

Comment: [edit] and add the full error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More information is needed. What error message is created?

You may need to make count a global variable:

```
global count
count = 0
@client.command()
async def addcan(ctx):
        global count
        count += 1
            await ctx.send(count)
            return count
```

Comment: Sorry about that! When I try running it, I get
```line 17, in addcan
    count += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment
```

Edit: I tried adding the global count, no change

Comment: Try defining count as global in the addcan() subroutine. I have changed the code above.

Comment: great! happy to help!